# Pass models to directive

Tags: angularjs

I created a `map` directive that wraps Google Maps API and creates a map with a marker given a certain coordenates:

```
<map latitude="-17.366449199999998" longitude="-66.1564083"></map>
```

I'm fetching the coordinates with a promise using [angularjs-geolocation](https://github.com/arunisrael/angularjs-geolocation):

```
geolocation.getLocation().then(function(data) {
  $scope.coords = _.pick(data.coords, 'latitude', 'longitude');
});
```

How can I pass the values from `$scope.coords` to map's isolated scope?

```
<map latitude="{{ coords.latitude }}" longitude="{{ coords.longitude }}"></map>
```

I tried setting directive's scope as:

```
scope: {
  coords: '&'
}
```

and passing the coords with:

```
<map coords="coords"></map>
```

I think that the fact that the coords are being fetched asynchronously with a promise is giving problems as it's not available during the creation of the map directive.

I'll post my directive's code:

```
angular.module('angularGeolocationApp').directive('map', function($log) {
  return {
    template: '<div class="google-map"></div>',
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    scope: {
      latitude: '@',
      longitude: '@'
    },
    link: function postLink(scope, element, attrs) {

      element.unwrap();

      var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(scope.latitude, scope.longitude);

      var map = new google.maps.Map(element.get(0), {
        zoom: 15,
        center: latlng,the
        mapTypeControl: false,
        navigationControlOptions: {
          style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.SMALL
        },
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
      });

      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latlng,
        map: map,
        title: 'You are here!'
      });
    }
  };
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
scope: {
  coords: '='
}

<map coords="coords"></map>
```

and in your link function

```
scope.$watch('coords', function ( coords ) {
    console.log(coords);
})
```

Comment: This works as expected, however, the first watch returns `scope.coords === undefined`. I'm doing `if(!scope.coords) return;` to workaround this, but is there a better way?

Comment: Define `$scope.coords` in your controller.

Answer (score 0):

In order to pass a javascript object like `coords`, you are going to need to use `=` on your isolated scope:

```
scope: {
  coords: '='
}
```

`=` will bind the entire object into the directive, where `@` will only bind the flattened attribute value into the directive.  So, `=` will pass by reference.  You will then have access to all the properties of the `coords` object inside your directive.

Then, when you use `coords`, it would look like this:

```
var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(scope.coords.latitude, scope.coords.longitude);
```

Answer (score 0):

'&' is used for parent context evaluation attribute. Use '=' instead for dual way binding attribute between an isolated scope and it's parent.

```
scope : {
 coords : "="
}
```

should do the trick.